# Getting a 3D view from Google Maps into QGIS?

Tags: 3d, google-maps-api, import, qgis-3

I guess it would be safe to assume that there is no straight-forward way of doing this, since 3D functionality was just rolled into QGIS, but is there a way of importing the 3D (tilted) view from the online google maps as a dynamic 3D basemap into QGIS?